# recursion in javascript making array, from codeacademy

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

```
      I want a recursive function that returns the powers of a number and stores each of them in an array called *stack*.
```

In other words, each time the recursion is executed, a new value will be added to the stack.

For example, if we called `power(3, 3)`, our stack should end up with the elements `[3, 9, 27]`.

However, the outcome of this code is 27 instead of the array. What is my mistake?

```
// Create an empty array called "stack"
var stack = [];
// Here is our recursive function
function power(base, exponent) {
    // Base case 
    if ( exponent === 0 ) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Recursive case
    else {
        stack[exponent - 1] = base * power(base, exponent - 1);
        return stack[exponent - 1];
    }
}
power(3,3);
```

Comment: Please edit your code to use proper indentation. It's very difficult to read.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's time and solutions, but I voted for what I can understand. Other codes I need time to study since I am a beginner. Thank you! Also, it has to be a recursion since I am studying recursion but still cannot understand how and when to use it, although I read eloquent javascript several times.

Comment: I meant eloquent javascript recursion part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you don't return the array, but the last calculated product. Actually, the result you are looking for is stored in *stack* after the call finishes.

But it is bad practice to have a global variable that gets mutated by a function. Instead create a so-called closure for it, and call it *powers* (plural, to indicate you get an array from it):

```js
function powers(base, exponent) {
    // Create an empty array called "stack"
    var stack = [];
    // Here is our recursive function
    function power(base, exponent) {
        // Base case 
        if ( exponent === 0 ) {
            return 1;
        }
         // Recursive case
        else {
            stack[exponent - 1] = base * power(base, exponent - 1);
            return stack[exponent - 1];
        }
    }
    power(base, exponent);
    return stack;
}
console.log(powers(3,3));
```

Made a bit more compact:

```js
function powers(base, exponent) {
    var stack = [];
    (function power(exponent) {
        return +!exponent || (stack[--exponent] = base * power(exponent));
    })(exponent);
    return stack;
}
console.log(powers(3,3));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your code. The only issue is the return value.
You can see below (BTW, I've minified your code little bit)

```js
var task = (() => {
  var stack = [];
  function power(base, exponent) {
    return (exponent && (stack[--exponent] = base * power(base, exponent))) || 1;
  }
  power(3, 3);
  return stack;
});
console.log(task());
```

I'm not fan of recursive calls personally and I don't prefer use that pattern unless there is a "have to" case.

So, In your case (Let's forget it is from codeacademy and let's consider that it is kind of real-life case) using a recursive function is not a mandatory.

There are many ways to achieve the same results above.

For example, classic for loop:

```js
function power(base, exp){
  var result = [];
  for(var i=1; i<=exp; i++){
    result.push(Math.pow(base, i));
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(power(3, 3));
```

Or, ES6 generators (maybe ?)

```js
function *power(base, exp){
  let prev = 1;
  for(var i=0; i<exp; i++){
    yield prev *= base;
  }
}

console.log([...power(3, 3)]);
```